# Terrain Navmesh build, rebuild smaller pieces of the bigger navmesh terrain. UNITY

Tags: unity, navmesh

when the area is very big and AI characters are required to walk a larger distance, it would be beneficial to have the large navmesh ready for finding a path.

when we change the height of the terrain in runtime small areas of the terrain should be updated.
so the buildnavmesh method is  kind of an overkill.
and the localnavmesh builder as a large type would be inefficient.
how do we dynamically change a small part of a larger navmesh?
advice or help would be highly appreciated.